# hadoop mapreduce to generate substrings of different lengths

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, shingles

Using Hadoop mapreduce I am writing code to get substrings of different lengths. Example given string "ZYXCBA" and length 3 (Using a text file i give input as "3 ZYXCBA"). My code has to return all possible strings of length 3 ("ZYX","YXC","XCB","CBA"), length 4("ZYXC","YXCB","XCBA") finally length 5("ZYXCB","YXCBA").

In map phase I did the following:

key = length of substrings I want

value = "ZYXCBA".

So mapper output is

```
3,"ZYXCBA"
4,"ZYXCBA"
5,"ZYXCBA"
```

In reduce I take string ("ZYXCBA") and key 3 to get all substrings of length 3. Same occurs for 4,5. Results are concatenated using a string. So out put of reduce should be :

```
3 "ZYX YXC XCB CBA"
4 "ZYXC YXCB XCBA"
5 "ZYXCB YXCBA"
```

I am running my code using following command:

```
hduser@Ganesh:~/Documents$ hadoop jar Saishingles.jar hadoopshingles.Saishingles Behara/Shingles/input Behara/Shingles/output
```

My code is as shown below:

```
package hadoopshingles;

import java.io.IOException;
//import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path; 
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;


public class Saishingles{

public static class shinglesmapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, IntWritable, Text>{

        public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
                ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            String str = new String(value.toString());
            String[] list = str.split(" ");
            int x = Integer.parseInt(list[0]);
            String val = list[1];
            int M = val.length();
            int X = M-1;


            for(int z = x; z <= X; z++)
            {
                context.write(new IntWritable(z), new Text(val));
            }

        }

     }


public static class shinglesreducer extends Reducer<IntWritable,Text,IntWritable,Text> {


    public void reduce(IntWritable key, Text value, Context context
            ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        int z = key.get();
        String str = new String(value.toString());
        int M = str.length();
        int Tz = M - z;
        String newvalue = "";
        for(int position = 0; position <= Tz; position++)
        {
            newvalue = newvalue + " " + str.substring(position,position + z);   
        }

        context.write(new IntWritable(z),new Text(newvalue));
    }
}




public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      GenericOptionsParser parser = new GenericOptionsParser(args);
      Configuration conf = parser.getConfiguration();
      String[] otherArgs = parser.getRemainingArgs();

        if (otherArgs.length != 2) 
        {
          System.err.println("Usage: Saishingles <inputFile> <outputDir>");
          System.exit(2);
        }
      Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "Saishingles");
      job.setJarByClass(hadoopshingles.Saishingles.class);
      job.setMapperClass(shinglesmapper.class);
      //job.setCombinerClass(shinglesreducer.class);
      job.setReducerClass(shinglesreducer.class);
      //job.setMapOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
      //job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
      job.setOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
      job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
      FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
      FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
      System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);

}

}
```

Output of reduce instead of returning

```
3 "ZYX YXC XCB CBA"
4 "ZYXC YXCB XCBA"
5 "ZYXCB YXCBA"
```

it's returning

```
3 "ZYXCBA"
4 "ZYXCBA"
5 "ZYXCBA"
```

i.e., it's giving same output as mapper. Don't know why this is happening. Please help me resolve this and thanks in advance for helping ;) :) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this without even running reducer. your map/reduce logic is wrong...transformation should be done in Mapper.

***[Reduce](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/mapred_tutorial.html#Reducer)*** - In this phase the `reduce(WritableComparable, Iterator, OutputCollector, Reporter)` method is called for each `<key, (list of values)>` pair in the grouped inputs.

in your `reduce` signature: `public void reduce(IntWritable key, Text value, Context context)`

should be `public void reduce(IntWritable key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)`

Also, change last line of reduce method: `context.write(new IntWritable(z),new Text(newvalue));` to `context.write(key,new Text(newvalue));` - you already have `Intwritable Key` from mapper, I wouldn't create `new` one.

*with given input:*

```
3 "ZYXCBA"
4 "ZYXCBA"
5 "ZYXCBA"
```

*Mapper job will output:*

```
3   "XCB YXC ZYX"
4   "XCBA YXCB ZYXC"
5   "YXCBA ZYXCB"
```

***MapReduceJob:***

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.Context;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

public class SubStrings{

    public static class SubStringsMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, IntWritable, Text> {

        @Override
        public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            String [] values = value.toString().split(" ");
            int len = Integer.parseInt(values[0].trim());
            String str = values[1].replaceAll("\"", "").trim();

            int endindex=len;
            for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            {
                endindex=i+len;
                if(endindex <= str.length())
                    context.write(new IntWritable(len), new Text(str.substring(i, endindex))); 
            }

        }   
    }

    public  static class SubStringsReducer extends Reducer<IntWritable, Text, IntWritable, Text> {

        public void reduce(IntWritable key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) 
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            String str="\""; //adding starting quotes
            for(Text value: values)
                str += " " + value;

            str=str.replace("\" ", "\"") + "\""; //adding ending quotes
            context.write(key, new Text(str));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "get-possible-strings-by-length");

        job.setJarByClass(SubStrings.class);
        job.setMapperClass(SubStringsMapper.class); 
        job.setReducerClass(SubStringsReducer.class);

        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
        FileSystem fs = null;
        Path dstFilePath = new Path(args[1]);
        try {
            fs = dstFilePath.getFileSystem(conf);
            if (fs.exists(dstFilePath))
                fs.delete(dstFilePath, true);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        job.waitForCompletion(true);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I have done same thing without a reducer. I want to know why my reducer isn't working in my code @BigDataLearner

Comment: see my updates in answer - you need to change `reduce` method implementation.